# Graphing parametric equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, parametric, parametrization, quadrics

I am very unsure as to how to graph $y = \exp(t)$, $z = \exp(t)\cos(t)$ and $x = \exp(t)\sin(t)$.

Initially, I thought the traces were circles parallel to the $xz$-plane and increased across the positive $y$-axis (where $y > 0$) in a spiral-like manner. Upon graphing it on matlab, it showed a single curve and now I'm confused as to where I may have went wrong or is it due to the limitations of matlab?

Comment: The factor $e^t$ is growing much faster than the way the curve is spinning. By the time the spiral has completed a half spin. $e^t$ has becomes $e^\pi \approx 23.14$ larger. In a full spin, the first half of spinning is concentrated at the $4$% of the tip of the spiral. If you don't know it is there, it is very likely you will miss that.... If you speed up the spining, i.e. replace $\cos(t),\sin(t)$ by $\cos(at),\sin(at)$, say for $a$ around $5$, you will see the spiral....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
z^{2} + x^{2} = \exp(2t)\cos^{2}(t) + \exp(2t)\sin^{2}(t) = \exp(2t) = y^{2}
\end{align*}